# What RDBMS command is used to tell what user has what permissions on a particular object?

Tags: rdbms

What RDBMS command is used to tell what user has what permissions on a particular object?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what your trying to check permissions on... I.E. oracle, mysql, mssql server, etc

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the database system you use. In Oracle, you can find out a lot by

```
select * from all_tab_privs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres [how to do it](http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/02/09/SQL-Server-2005_3A00_-View-all-permissions.aspx) in sql server 2005

```
select dp.NAME AS principal_name,
    dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
    o.NAME AS object_name,
    p.permission_name,
    p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
    sys.database_permissions p
    OUTER JOIN sys.all_objects o
on     p.major_id = o.OBJECT_ID
inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
```